# How to find unknown number of rows and cols from input file?

Tags: c++, file-io

So the input file will look similar to this, it can be arbitrary..:

```
000001000101000
010100101010000
101010000100000
```

I need to be able to find how many rows and columns are in the input file before I can start reading the file into a 2d array and I don't know if this is the right way to do it:

```
char c;
fin.get(c);
COLS = 0;

while ( c != '\n' && c != ' ')
{
    fin.get(c);
    ++COLS;
}

cout << "There are " << COLS << " columns in this text file" << endl;


ROWS = 1;
string line;
while ( getline( fin, line ))
    ++ROWS;


cout << "There are " << ROWS << " rows in this text file" << endl;
```

If this is not the right way to do it or there is a more simple way please help me out.

**I ALSO CAN'T USE THE STRING LIBRARY**

Comment: You can just read the first line to get the number of columns, and then divide the file size to that to get the number of lines. This way you skip reading the whole file

Comment: Also, for the number of columns, instead of reading one character at a time, read with getline and then get the size of the string.

Comment: Hmmm.. sorry but what would that code look like? @bolov

Comment: Your current code misses all the data in the first row.

How big is the maximum input file? It might be easiest to just read the entire file into RAM and parse it using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @JonWatte Yes I'm pretty sure I need to use pointers because the file is going to be pretty big up to 100x100

Comment: if you can't use string library so what is line in your getline( fin, line)?

Comment: @piotruś that works without including the string library

Comment: @MattRay Because you are including other header files which in turn include `<string>`. If you can't use `std::string` update your question so that the code correctly reflects your requirements.

Comment: @MattRay That is not at all accurate.  You are declaring an instance of `std::string` (`line`), and `std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)` is in the `<string>` header.  If you meant to use `std::istream::getline`, then you would need to use a character buffer.

Comment: Why can't you use `std::string`? I highly suggest you use the standard library, otherwise you're going to end up with some ugly c/c++ mash. In addition to `std::string` I also highly suggest using something like a `std::vector` or `std::list` to store the lines so that you only need one pass through the file. Finally, if you're deciding the file format consider putting the size of your array at the top.

Comment: 100x100 is not a big file, unless you're working on the smallest of embedded microcontrollers. It's less than 10 kilobytes; easy to read into memory in a single read call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can read it faster this way:

```
// get length of file:
fin.seekg (0, is.end);
int fileSize = fin.tellg();
fin.seekg (0, fin.beg);

std::string s;
if( getline( fin, s)) {
  cols = s.size();
  rows = fileSize/(cols+1);  // cols+1 to count also '\n' at the end of each line
}
```

Comment: Okay sweet, I can see how this works but what do I put where you put "filesize"

Comment: This is working but what is "filesize" what do I put there? because that doesnt work

Comment: @MattRay tellg() can be used to tell the file size

Comment: That is probably not going to work very well since new lines and potentially other non-printable characters are included in `fileSize` but not in the length of the string created with `getline`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious how to correct this then? should it be rows = fileSize/(cols+1); at least to count also '\n's ?

Comment: @piotruś Well a very basic fix of narrow scope would be to do something like `rows = fileSize / (cols + 1)` to account for a single new line character and ONLY that at the end of each line. If the data file retains a strict format that _should_ address the problem. You may need to change `1` to `2` if you are on a Windows platform with CR/LF combinations at the end of each line.

Comment: if OP is on a windows platform. Thanks.

Comment: Okay so is there a way to do this without using std::string? @piotruś

Comment: @MattRay If you need to cease using `std::string` I suggest giving it the old community college try and post another question if you run into problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to use `std::string` and `std::vector`, this problem becomes trivial:

```
std::istream_iterator<std::string> start(fin); // fin is your std::ifstream instance
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
std::vector<std::string> lines(start, end);
```

Since each line contains no spaces, the vector will hold all of your lines.  Assuming each line is the same width, each string should be of the same length (you can check that easy enough by iterating through the vector and checking the lengths).

Comment: @MattRay Additionally, if you cannot use `std::string`, why are you doing it in your current code (`string line; getline(fin, line)`) - as well as in the answer you accepted?